# Get data from token method using web3

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have a smart contract deployed with the following function:

```
function getInfo(address foo) public view returns (uint256[] memory){

  return to_raise[foo];

}
```

my question is: how do I call getInfo(myaddress) using web3 (and get the number it returns)?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a working answer thanks to this question and answer: [How to get result from contract function called through web3 using sendTransaction](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/66793/how-to-get-result-from-contract-function-called-through-web3-using-sendtransacti?rq=1)

and thanks to somedocumentation: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html

The following code is working

```
async function doAnotherThing(){


  var address = "0xcee911a1bd2341a5ac878652f4505f14f3fdfc6c";// contract address

  const jsonInterface = [/* your abi here */]

  var MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(jsonInterface, address);

  // set provider for all later instances to use
  MyContract.setProvider('wss://blissful-frequent-energy.bsc-testnet.discover.quiknode.pro/YOURAPIKEYHERE/');

  try{

    MyContract.methods.getInfo(accounts[0]).call({from: accounts[0]}, function(error, result){
    alert( result)
  });


  // MyContract.methods.getInfo.call({from:accounts[0]}).then( value => alert(value))
  
  }catch(error){
    alert(error)

  }


}
```